# The property was not found in ObjectdataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, objectdataprovider

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=String46 , Source={StaticResource CurrentResources}}">
```

This code works at runtime, and there are no errors when building the project.
However, each time I modify the xaml code 'String46' is underlined with the following tooltip :

`"The property was not found in ObjectdataProvider".`

This only appears in VS2017, not in older VS versions.

Comment: Did you try a full rebuild.?

Comment: yep, when full rebuild this message disappear , but if i change something in the xaml code , the error come back again.